# How do you collect multiple tables into a single table?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to complete this task set to me, which is to write a piece of code which would collect multiple separated tables in a CSV spreadsheet file into a single table in another. The tables are all of different lengths, and there is the possibility that all of Table1 will not be used (a challenge to tackle at a later date, but I imagine will just be as simple as picking and choosing which Variables are moved to the new file).

[Mockup Example Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAcdU.png)

[Mockup Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfPdX.png)

The intention is to run the code to build out that single file with multiple entries from other files. However, it is the process of efficiently getting the data renamed, reorganised, and into a different format which I am struggling with.

I've been looking at utilising Python, and have variable ideas of parts of the code, such as;

- Renaming the particular variables with 'as', though I don't know if it could be a case which used a case and concatenation or is individually tackled one at a time.
- identifying the particular files for conversion, though this is something which I have been putting off for the end as this will undoubtably be the final step.

Comment: What is the file format? CSV?

Comment: Yes, they are all in CSV files

Comment: Please post a minimal example with CSV files, it's too time consuming to try to decipher the format from your screenshots

Comment: Apologies, I am new to Stack and wanted to quickly get something mocked up to reflect the source material. Because I'm so new, it won't allow me to put photos up - just the links.

For the format, you have four tables with a different number of variables each. It doesn't have to be the exact length, but the idea is to get them all merged into one table with new names reflecting the tables they came from - VARIABLE A from TABLE 1 would have the new name 'TABLE1_VARA'.

Comment: That's fine can you post a minimal CSV using the code sample formatting?

Comment: Apologies for the delay @AlexW , we made a breakthrough with the task and I wanted to focus on continuing the momentum...apologies I was unable to get you the minimal CSV.  I hope that the way the code tackles the CSV file helps clarify what I was tackling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to the community, and patience to those who helped me find the answer. Thanks for @Aleff for helping link to pandas, and ultimately we did end up tackling the tables in a standard way. Apologies again to @AlexW for being unable to provide the minimal csv file in the code sample format.

Below is the code we managed to craft together to tackle the file and the various tables. One of the main issues we faced was that the file was file was being produced by a database which was formatting it in a specific way, hence why there is a lot of additional stuff to the code (including a column specifier, as this was used to isolate specific columns to carry across).

```
Import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 0, nrows = 1, usecols [1 , 2,  3])
df1.columns = ‘TABLE1_’ + df1.columns
df2 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 2, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df2.columns = ‘TABLE2_’ + df2.columns
df3 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 4, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df3.columns = ‘TABLE3_’ + df3.columns
df4 = pd.read_csv (“file.csv”, sep=’\t’, encoding = ‘utf-16', header = 6, nrows = 1, usecols [1, 2, 3])
df4.columns = ‘TABLE4_’ + df4.columns

df5 = df1.join([df2, df3, df4])
df5.to_csv(“file_output.csv”, sep = ’,’, encoding = ‘utf-8’, header = True, index = False)
```

I hope others find this informative. Many thanks again to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating different tables but with the same structure is possible and is useful, concatenating different tables with different structures is also possible but the result may not be what you expect, in which case you can standardize the tables or write a program that performs the concatenation as you prefer.

In your case (Input and Output) you have tables with totally different structures and, therefore, it would not make sense to simply concatenate them. In this case the best thing would be to use the [Pandas librar](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/)y to edit your tables in a standard way and then join them together **or** to work directly on the data by creating a new file that satisfies what you want.

Comment: Thanks, a friend has mentioned using Pandas - I'm just a little inexperienced in using it myself, and so I've been trying to get my head around the specific functions to employ to get it to work.

Comment: The [Pandas library](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp) is one of the best for working on very large datased so I encourage you to study it because it can certainly give you what you are looking for.
I would encourage you, however, to also check if you have the ability to change the way you save that data, for example if you are generating these tables as a result of a test phase and you want to save the results then try to change the output so you will directly have tables with equivalent structures.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have been able to make a breakthrough with the code - using pandas to tackle each table individually, and get to that end point.